# Using Console.app - how to find disk force eject logs?

Tags: macos, mac, external-disk, console

I've been having a number of issues with external disks force unmounting (most often while waking from sleep).

Where can I look in Console.app to track down the potential issue?

Answer (score 2):

Choose All messages on the sidebar.

Filter by mount (or unmount)

and that is it

for example on my OS X 10.10.2 Mac mini

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, is there anyway to narrow that down further — looking for only improperly ejected mounts?

Comment: If you could define improperly :)

Comment: Any unmount that wasnt ejected properly, as in the drive was in use and or mounted when it became unmounted - thus causing an error notification about it not being ejected properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way in Catalina, hope that helps also for the other MacOS versions.

1. In Catalina, you first need to export the log to your home directory by typing the following command in your terminal:

   sudo log collect --last 1d

You can adjust the "--last" part and narrow down the dates.

2. Open the exported "system_logs.logarchive" in your home directory by double clicking it. And type "media is not present" in the search bar. You will see that for each "not properly eject" event, multiple entries were written in nearly the same time (I have twice force removed my usb for the sake of science). You can then inspect those event closely or search the log for further information.

[image]